# Highcharts data doesn't show up correctly

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a chart that shows the time in and time out for the employees on a daily basis. I've fetched the data from the database and all was working well. But now the columns show the data incorrectly in the chart. I can't figure out why it is so. Can anybody help me on this?

[This is my chart. The column is always full no matter what value is set.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwlJF.png)

[This is the data that is coming from the json file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKzUY.png)

```js
function InitHighChart()
{
    $("#chart").html("Wait, Loading graph...");

    var options = {
            chart: {
            type: 'column',
            renderTo: 'chart',
            zoomType: 'xy',
            backgroundColor:'transparent'
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: '<?php echo $name; ?>\'s Attendence',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            categories: [{}],
            labels: {
                rotation: -20,
            }           
        },
         yAxis: {

            type: 'datetime',
            plotBands: [{ 
                from: 1447747200000,
                to: 1447779600000,
                color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, 0.1)',
                zIndex: 5,
               label: {
                    text: 'Office Timing',
                     style: {
                        color: '#606060'
                    } 
                } 
            }],
             plotLines: [{
                    //value: $inavg,
                    color: 'green',
                    dashStyle: 'shortdash',
                    width: 2,
                    label: {
                        text: 'Average Time In'
                    },
                    zIndex: 5
                }, {
                    //value: $outavg,
                    color: 'red',
                    dashStyle: 'shortdash',
                    width: 2,
                    label: {
                        text: 'Average Time Out'
                    },
                    zIndex: 5
                }],

        dateTimeLabelFormats: {

            minute: '%l:%M %p',
            hour: '%l:%M %p'

        },
        min: 1447729200000,
            max: 1447797600000,
        tickInterval:  1000,
                title: {
                    text: 'Time'
                }
            }, 
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                var s = '<b>'+ this.x +'</b>';

                $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
                     s += '<br/>'+  point.series.name + ':  ' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%l:%M %p', point.y)
                });

                return s;
            },
            shared: true
        },
        series: [{},{}]
    };  

    $.ajax({
        url: "json.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>",
        type:'post',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            options.xAxis.categories = data.categories;
            options.yAxis.plotLines[0].value = data.inavg;
            options.yAxis.plotLines[1].value = data.outavg;
            options.series[0].name = 'Time In';
            options.series[0].data = data.timein;
            options.series[1].name = 'Time Out';
            options.series[1].data = data.timeout;
            console.log(options);
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);          
        }
    });
}





<?php 
require_once("session.php"); 
require_once("connection.php");
$id= $_GET['id'];   
$query= "SELECT * ";
$query.= "FROM attendence ";
$query.= "WHERE emp_id = {$id}";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
if(!$result){
echo ("Database query failed. ".mysqli_connect_error());
}  
$categories=array();
$timein=array();
$timeout=array();
$avrgi="";
$avrgo="";
$count=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
$categories[]= $row['date'];
$itime=$row['time_in'];
$split=str_split($itime, 11);
$timei=end($split);
$timein[]= strtotime($timei)*1000;
$otime=$row['time_out'];
$osplit=str_split($otime, 11);
$timeo=end($osplit);
$timeout[]= strtotime($timeo)*1000;
$avrgi+=strtotime($timei)*1000;
$avrgo+=strtotime($timeo)*1000;
$count++;
} 
$inavg= $avrgi/$count;
$outavg= $avrgo/$count;      

$graph_data=array('categories'=>$categories,'timein'=>$timein,
'timeout'=>$timeou    t,'inavg'=>$inavg,'outavg'=>$outavg);
echo json_encode($graph_data);
exit;
?>
```

Comment: At the beginning I advice you to sort your data by x asceding, which is requirement for Highcharts. Then let me know if problem still appears.

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to see the chart live, I am guessing that you are sending data that is beyond your axis max value.

If the data in your code above, and the data in your linked image are accurate, that is indeed the case.  So the bars extend beyond the end of the plot area.

You are setting a min and max on your axis based on a the first date, but then sending data data to the series for the individual dates. that can't work...

If you want to plot multiple dates against a time axis, you will need to process and abstract your data by, for example, number of seconds, rather than using a time stamp.

Comment: but when i comment out the min and max values that also dosn't work. i don't know why but all was working well even with min and max values, the cart was showing the accurate time in the plot area but then it gone wrong.  this is the php script that i used to fetch the data from the database

Comment: oh it worked. when i zoom to the values it shows the correct value. bt how to formate the yAxis so it always shows the value that are in the plot area ???